# Stopping Windows Update before logging

Tags: windows-update

I have an old laptop with Win7. It is for a week stuck in updating at 35% before login (I cannot login with any way-around)

I have a dual boot system with Lubuntu 16.04.

Can anyone suggest some file or something which can be altered/moved/renamed/deleted using lubuntu which stop this process, and let me login.

Kamran
Islamabad, Pakistan

[ my actual problem ends here, below is just a reason why I have to do this ]

For some reason I cannot re-install windows. Laptop shuts-down when installing Win7 (after the second phase of loading-files).

Someone suggested the problematic RAM. Running memtest86+ from GRUB multi-boot screen also shuts-down the laptop after a couple of minutes (i.e. not giving any hint to RAM error). Even I tried to replace both RAM sticks one by one, and the behaviour is same.

Comment: The shutdown is almost certainly a heat issue. Make sure your vent is cleaned with high pressure air and that the fan is spinning properly. This probably contributed to the position you are in now because the laptop is shutting off in the middle of updates.

Answer (score -1):

You need to open your Laptop, get it cleaned and apply thermal paste on the processor. 
And most probably, you need to reinstall your windows, as it seems corrupted and stuck in a boot-loop. I advice you to upgrade your PC to Windows 10, as it super smooth.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But that is not the case. When in Windows or Lubuntu any processor intensive task takes even 100% of CPU, and laptop's fan runs full-speed, it never halts (or shuts down).